# Cross domain cookies not sent via XHR in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have two domains:

1. app.red.com - I have cookies set on this domain (on *.red.com)
2. web.blue.com

From web.blue.com, I'm making a client-side XHR call to app.red.com:

```javascript
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://app.red.com/someapi', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);
```

In Chrome 57, this XHR request does NOT send the cookies I have associated with *.red.com.

Trying to replicate the same behavior with Firefox 32 results in the cookies being sent.

The browser versions may not be relevant - other members of my team are using many different versions (including 57), and none of them see the problem.

Are there any Chrome-specific flags or settings specific to my system that might cause this?